# Cannot launch MathLink from C

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp

I am trying to launch a MathLink from a 64bit C dll that I am building, using the following code:

```
#include "mathlink.h"

static MLENV ep = (MLENV)0;
static MLINK lp = (MLINK)0;

__declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall init()
{
  int err;
  char * argv[3];
  int success = 1;

  argv[0] = "-linklaunch";
  argv[1] = "-linkname";
  argv[2] = "'\"C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram Research\\Mathematica\\9.0\\MathKernel.exe\" -mathlink'";

  ep =  MLInitialize((char *)0);
  if(ep == (MLENV)0) success = 0;

  lp = MLOpenArgcArgv(ep, 3, argv, &err);

  if(lp == (MLINK)0) success = err;

  return success;
}
```

However, when calling this `init()` function, I always get the error code 34, indicating that the specified link protocol is unavailable. I tried specifying a link protocol (SharedMemory,Pipes,...) using the `-linkprotocol` argument for `MLOpenArgcArgv()`, but without any change.

Although the error code referes to the link protocol, I also tried different formats for the MathKernel.exe directory (e.g. `\\\\` for backslashes, different quotes, ...), but nothing changed. Using 0 for argc and a null pointer for argv also doesn't change anything.

The necessary files for MathLink devices (mlshm64.mlp etc.) are all in their correct place (System32 folder for x64).
I can also launch the MathKernel.exe from the command line without problems, and a different C program using MathLink which I'm accessing through the `Install[]` function in Mathematica is running fine on the same computer.

My system:

- Win7 x64
- Mathematica 9
- DLL compiled with MinGW x64, using an import library for ml64i3.dll generated with gendef/dlltool (see http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2012/Jun/msg00323.html)

Any ideas what could be causing this error?

**Edit**
I now got the same code running by compiling it in Visual Studio 2013 as a DLL and linking to the same MathLink DLL - still not sure why compiling in MinGW doesn't work though.

Comment: Good question. I don't know either. Could be slightly different ABIs between VS and MinGW? This should not really happen but there are subtle differences such as stack alignment and the length of a `long double`, amonst other things.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Win7 64bit with Mathematica 10.0. I have resolved it by removing **-mathlink** from the options sent to MathKernel, this means that WSOpenArgcArgv should receive the following list of options:

```
argc=5;
argv[0]=name_of_your_executable;
argv[1]="-linkmode";
argv[2]="launch";
argv[3]="-linkname";
argv[4]="\"c:\\Program Files\\Wolfram Research\\Mathematica\\10.0\\MathKernel\"";
```

(*or where your MathKernel stored*)

PS This would be equivalent to running your program from the command line with the following options:

```
***.exe -linkmode launch -linkname "c:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\10.0\MathKernel"
```

and then simply passing argc, argv from main.

**PS** Of course written above relates to version 10.0 and current WSTP protocol, but necessary changes to run it in your case should be straightforward.