# choose a WSTP program to launch

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp

When I run an external program(compiled by Visul C++ 2012 in windows 7) to use the wolframkernal by WTSP, for example:project1.exe -linkmode launch,it will open a dialog box named "choose a WSTP program to launch" to choose mathkernal.exe or wolframkernal.exe to evaluate expression transferred by the program. If I don't want the dialog box to be shown, the program can directly launch the kernal by WSTP, what shall I do? Thank you!

Comment: ref:http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/49261/cannot-launch-mathlink-from-c?rq=1